# pandas dataframe vectorize for loop with logical statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

i want to vectorize following function in python. i am havin 50000 rows in dataframe , so need to make it happen fast and so vectorization for following code is needed in python

```
for i in range(1,len(df)):
        if(df['temperature'].iloc[i]>df['temperature'].iloc[i-1]):
            df['delta'].iloc[i]=df['qty'].iloc[i]
            df['value'].iloc[i]=1
        elif(df['temperature'].iloc[i]<df['temperature'].iloc[i-1]):
            df['delta'].iloc[i]=-1*df['qty'].iloc[i]
            df['value'].iloc[i]=-1
        elif(df['temperature'].iloc[i]==df['temperature'].iloc[i-1]):
            df['delta'].iloc[i]=df['value'].iloc[i-1]*df['qty'].iloc[i]
            df['value'].iloc[i]=df['value'].iloc[i-1]
```

Comment: please add a sample dataframe with both your input & output examples see [mcve]

Comment: May be [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this will do the job, but without input and expected output to compare with, I can't check:

```
gt_idx = df['temperature'] > df.shift(-1)['temperature']
df.loc[gt_idx, 'delta'] = df.loc[gt_idx, 'qty']
df.loc[gt_idx, 'value'] = 1

lt_idx = df['temperature'] < df.shift(-1)['temperature']
df.loc[lt_idx, 'delta'] = df.loc[lt_idx, 'qty'] * -1
df.loc[lt_idx, 'value'] = -1

eq_idx = df['temperature'] == df.shift(-1)['temperature']
df.loc[eq_idx, 'delta'] = df.shift(-1).loc[eq_idx, 'value'] *df.loc[eq_idx, 'qty']
df.loc[eq_idx, 'value'] = df.shift(-1).loc[eq_idx, 'value']
```

Comment: it starts from 1 . how to control that part??

Comment: it starts from 1 . how to control that part??  for loop starts from 1 and not zero

Comment: The very first row will not have any comparisons made, because the shifted columns will have NaN values. So effectively, this code also starts from index 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), as follows:

```
cond_list = [df['temperature'] > df['temperature'].shift(),
             df['temperature'] < df['temperature'].shift(),
             df['temperature'] = df['temperature'].shift()
            ]

choice_list = [(df['delta'] = df['qty'], df['value'] = 1),
               (df['delta'] = - df['qty'], df['value'] = -1),
               (df['delta'] = df['qty'] * df['value'].shift(), df['value'] = df['value'].shift())
              ] 
              
np.select(cond_list, choice_list)
```